# javascript, promises, как создать и последовательно выполнить очередь задач

Tags: javascript

Прошу помощи. Есть у меня массив `queue = []`, в него кладутся задачи на выполнение. Там могут быть задачи как локального, так и ajax типа. Мне необходимо последовательное выполнение задач из массива, но разумеется строго после того, как была выполнена предыдущая. Для пример массив слушается каждые три секунды на предмет появления новых задач. Подскажите пожалуйста, я так понимаю, тут для последовательного выполнения надо как то `promises` задействовать, но я вообще не пойму, с какой стороны подползти к реализации

```
let
queue = [local_f1, local_f2, ajax_f3, ajax_f4...]

setInterval()
{
    if(queue.length > 0)
    {
        let
        action = queue.pop();

        console.log(action)
    }
},
3000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let queue = [local1, local2, ajax1, local1];

function local1() {
  console.log("local1");
}

function local2() {
  console.log("local2");
}

async function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

async function ajax1() {
  //Эмулируем долгую задачу
  await sleep(4000);
  console.log("ajax");
}
let isRun = false;
setInterval(async() => {
  if (isRun) return;
  isRun = true;
  if (queue.length > 0) {
    let action = queue.pop();
    if (action.constructor.name == "Function") {
      action();
    } else {
      await action();
    }
  }
  isRun = false;
}, 3000);
```